# Doctrine updating many to many association after deserialization

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am making something like a wizard and I need to pass an object from one request to another. I use serialization for this. The object is a doctrine entity with a many to many association. For demonstration purposes I will simplify, since this issue regards only the association.

```
class User 
{

    // scalar properties

    /**
     * @var User\Role
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Role", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="roles")
     */
    protected $roles;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Now, when I deserialize the object, it deserializes perfectly, with the associations. Problem is, when I merge it with $em->merge($object); and then flush, the object gets saved into database and all the scalar properties that changed are persisted correctly. But the association is ignored during save. Before saving, there are three roles in the database. I have only one role in my association, but when I flush and then reload the object from database, there are still the three roles that were there before. This issue occurs only with deserialization, if I work with an entity that is originaly loaded from $em, the association gets updated like it should.

One more thing - if I define cascade={"merge"} on the association, the merge operation ends with error "spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given" in UnitOfWork on line 1810, where an array of roles (in this case with one element) is passed into spl_object_hash() function. Not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Does anyone have and idea how to get around this issue, or what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the **EXACT** same issue today, that's why I landed here.
It seems I have solved it:

```
cascade={"merge"}
```

was definitely useful and once I configured the ManyToMany relation correctly on both sides, it started working - no "spl_objects_hash()"-issue any more. Pay Attention to inversedBy and Mapped by. Also, but I don't know if this is part of the trick, take a look at the add and remove methods (which I implemented on both sides.) Before, I didn't take care of adding/removing the other side of the relation...

```
class User {

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Project", cascade={"merge"}, inversedBy="users")

 * @JMS\Type("Relation<App\Entity\Project>")
 */
private $projects;
public function addProject(Project $project): self
{
    if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
        $this->projects[] = $project;
        $project->addUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeProject(Project $project): self
{
    if ($this->projects->contains($project)) {
        $this->projects->removeElement($project);
        $project->removeUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
}
class Project {
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="projects")
 * @JMS\Type("Relation<App\Entity\Project>")
 */
private $users;
}
```

EDIT: SO after having the same issue with another entity, I tested if the removing and adding of the related entity in add()/remove() was necessary in this case: NOPE. cascade={merge} does the trick, which started working after configuring the inverse side correctly.